# adding security to embedded jetty

Tags: authentication, jetty

I have a problem configuring BASIC-auth in jetty
here's my web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>resources</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>MyRealm</realm-name>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <role-name>user</role-name>
</security-role>
```

and here's my java code where I try to add a LoginService

```
HashLoginService myrealm = new HashLoginService("MyRealm");
    myrealm.setConfig("src/main/resources/jetty-realm.properties");
    root.getSecurityHandler().setLoginService(myrealm);
```

my jetty-realm.properties file has following user

```
user: Lag976JGQdeosfQM,user
```

I can make a connection but I can't authenticate, and I'm stuck on this for a long time now, so whoever helps me out get's a free digital beer! ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok so I've found out what I didn't do,
you have to start a LoginService before you can use it so I changed my java code to

```
HashLoginService myrealm = new HashLoginService("MyRealm");

myrealm.setConfig("src/main/resources/jetty-realm.properties");
myrealm.start();

root.getSecurityHandler().setLoginService(myrealm);
```

Comment: What is `root` parameter? And should I put this inside `contextInitialized()`?